# First attempt to migrate EC2 MySQL to Amazon RDS no going well - SUPER privileges

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've been trying to move an existing db from MySQL running on EC2 to a new Amazon RDS instance (an experiment to see if we can move across). So far, it's not going well. I'm stuck at the initial import before setting up replication (instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html)).

I've prepared the RDS instance as described and can connect to it from the EC2 instance using mysql. I ran the mysqldump command as:

`mysqldump --master-data --databases db1 db2 > dump.sql`

Then attempted to upload it to RDS with:

`mysql -h RDSHost -P 3306 -u rdsuser --password=rdspassword < dump.sql`

The first problem was at line 22 of the dump:

> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000002', MASTER_LOG_POS=106;

This line caused error `ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 22: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`. No problem, just commented out that line and hope to fix it later via mysql.rds_set_external_master(). Retried the upload, and got a very similar error: `ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 7844: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`. The section around line 7844 looks like this:

```
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`dev`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `jos_contributor_ids_view` AS select `jos_resource_contributors_view`.`uidNumber` AS `uidNumber` from `jos_resource_contributors_view` union select `jos_wiki_contributors_view`.`uidNumber` AS `uidNumber` from `jos_wiki_contributors_view` */;
```

By commenting out the first 2 lines and adding a 'CREATE' to the third,I was able to get past this one. But there are *tons* of sections like this. Is there some way round this without all the editing? Like an option to `mysqldump` to not produce anything which needs SUPER privileges?

It seems like lots of people have had similar problems, like having to run `sed` against the output of mysqldump / mysqlbinlog! I'm going to post on the AWS forum too - really I think RDS should have a more tolerant way of importing from mysqldump, or a specific tool which can be run against an existing db to create a dump which is complaint with RDS security. Just wondered if anyone had any other recipes or tricks which might help here.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Sorry - forgot to say that I've tried changing the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` parameter to 1, but still get the same error at line 7844.

Comment: Old post, but the first error you can avoid by saying `--masterdata=2`. The line will then be commented out in the dump.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You do likely need `log_bin_trust_function_creators` = 1 on RDS but that isn't the issue, here.

> You can specify a `DEFINER` value other than your own account only if you have the `SUPER` privilege.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-security.html</sup>

When a stored program (proc, function, event, or trigger) is running, everything it does has the permissions of the user who defined it, or of the user explicitly stated with a `DEFINER` declaration.  This allows, among other things, for stored programs to permit other users to do things to data they don't directly have permission to manipulate, as long as they have permission to use the stored program itself.

It would be a serious vulnerability, then, if a non-`SUPER` user could create a procedure with an arbitrary definer, because the user could escalate his or her privileges at will.

This is also true of views, of course, when the definer security context is used, as in the example you posted.

One of the biggest complaints I have with RDS is that you can't have `SUPER`... and now it can be one of yours, too :) because that fact is the cause of the problem you are having.

Of course, if I were running a managed MySQL service, I wouldn't give anybody `SUPER`, either, so their security model makes sense, even if it is sometimes unwieldy.

If all of your objects have the same definer, a workaround would be to restore the dump using that account instead of the one you're using now, but that seems unlikely.

Deleting just the line with the `DEFINER` declaration should make the dumpfile work in cases where it appears on a line by itself, or you could use sed or perl to modify the file... an idea that I already know you're not fond of, but it really is a nice thing about MySQL that such hackery is quite legitimate, and not really all that far afield from the kinds of things I have to do as  a DBA even in a non-RDS envirnoment.

```
perl -pe 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`//' < oldfile.sql > newfile.sql
```

...possibly not the answer you hoped for, but you could run that against your dumpfile and should end up with a slightly more usable file.

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive reply, and for confirming what I thought about sed / perl being the only solution. The app I'm using is highly customised Joomla, and whilst open-source I don't have the time / skill to analyse it to work out if it will move across to RDS well. My thought was 'try it and see' - but it seems like the first step is the hardest - in no small part due to Amazon's inadequate (in my view) migration tools. I agree on the security model, but if the default output of mysqldump creates so many problems, why don't they have a better solution? I will ask this of them too.

Comment: AWESOME.  thank you so much for that perl script.  my backup was 4+ GB and just opening it was a challenge.  this saved my day.

Comment: Great explanation, great answer, and great solution! Stupid definer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your perl one liner. It's the only one I've been able to find that actually works. Many others on these boards simply don't. I'd upvote again if I could.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was the "CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE= ... " line in the dump that was giving me the error.
This line was added by the "--master-data" option of mysqldump.
In Amazon AWS you need to start replication by setting the master details with "mysql.rds_set_external_master" procedure instead read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html)

So I just toke notes of that line "head 22 backup.dump" where the line 22 reported in the error.
Then remove it before importing, for my big file I use: "sed '22d' backup.dump > backup_clean.dump"