# Migrate my mysql database to AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, google-compute-engine

I have my MYSQL server running in my google instance. My server have vesta control panel where I'm currently managing servers.. I would like to migrate my database to Amazon RDS. How I can do it through google instance SSH.

Some of info that may help for answer:

I already created database instance in RDS where I allowed all IP to access (for now)

If you know way to do it through Mysql workspace , please share .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving MySQL databases without mysqldump](http://serverfault.com/questions/384100/saving-mysql-databases-without-mysqldump)

Comment: Also take a look at this Servr Fault  search which has plenty of other seful information. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Aserverfault.com+%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql&oq=site%3Aserverfault.com+%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.16203j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=site:serverfault.com+copy+%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql

Answer (score 3):

Working with RDS is no different than any other MySQL instance.

Run mysqldump to back up your database, transfer that file to a host that has access to your RDS instance, and then load that dump into RDS as you would normally do.

Comment: True, except that RDS is a bit trickier, lacking the `SUPER` privilege. http://serverfault.com/questions/555953/first-attempt-to-migrate-ec2-mysql-to-amazon-rds-no-going-well-super-privilege

Comment: Could you please explain as steps , where I can run on google ssh (not on workspace)

Comment: There are many tutorials online that walk you through this. We don't give out tutorials on Server Fault.